# Mule custom filemessagereceiver - polling configuration

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am new to mule. I want to receive files from local folder using poll() method.Could anyone tell me how to write override poll() for custom filemessagereceiver?

Comment: Why do you want to use a custom filemessagereceiver, while out of the box the file inbound endpoint will poll it for you?

Comment: what is the use case for overriding FMR?

Answer (score 0):

In the`CustomFileReceiver` class which extends `FileReceiver`, you can override all the inherited methods such as `processFiles`, `poll` etc like this

```
public class CustomFileReceiver extends FileMessageReceiver {

public CustomFileReceiver(org.mule.api.transport.Connector connector, FlowConstruct flowConstruct, InboundEndpoint endpoint,
        String readDir, String moveDir, String moveToPattern, long frequency) throws CreateException {
    super(connector, flowConstruct, endpoint, readDir, moveDir, moveToPattern, frequency);
}

@Override
public void poll() {
    // perform your special poll

}
```

}

HTH

Comment: Thanks Anil kumar. I did the same way, but I am not able to list files inside poll() method. Not able to add Override annotation for listFiles(). If I remove annotation, got warning as "The method CustomFileMessageReceiver.listFiles() does not override the inherited method from FileMessageReceiver since it is private to a different package".

Comment: The scope of the listFiles() method is default and it can't be overridden from FileMessageReceiver. If your requirement is to overwrite the default scoped methods along with poll() method then you need to either extend the AbstractPollingMessageReceiver or AbstractMessageReceiver and mimic the logic of FileMessageReceiver in your custom class.

Comment: and then use the tag <service-overrides messageReceiver="<custom_class_name>"/>

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried the same way you mentioned, Its working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the update, please make sure to vote/accept the answer if it helps you so that others can refer and benefit. thakns